# Code optimization, Pad missing keys and Total part of values

Tags: list-manipulation

#### Code optimization, Pad missing keys and Total part of values

---

```
fun[list_] := (temp = TakeWhile[list, #1[[1]] < 10 &];
temp~Join~Thread[{Complement[Range[9], temp[[All, 1]]], 0}]~

    Join~{{10, Total[ttt = Complement[list, temp][[All, 2]]]}});

list = Table[Range[20], {2}] // Transpose

(*
    {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5},{6,6},{7,7},{8,8},{9,9},{10,10},{11,11},{12,12},{13,13},{14
,14},{15,15},{16,16},{17,17},{18,18},{19,19},{20,20}}
*)

fun[list]

(*
    {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5},{6,6},{7,7},{8,8},{9,9},{10,165}}
*)
```

The function is to accumulate all numbers in whose index in greater than 9

```
(*
    {}
*)

l2 = {Take[#, 9], Take[#, {10, -1}]} &@list

(*
    {{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5},{6,6},{7,7},{8,8},{9,9}},{{10,10},{11,11},{12,12},{13,13},
{14,14},{15,15},{16,16},{17,17},{18,18},{19,19},{20,20}}}
*)

listFinal =  Append[Take[#, 9] &@list, {10, Total@list[[All, 2]][[10 ;; -1]]}]

(*
    {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5},{6,6},{7,7},{8,8},{9,9},{10,165}}
*)
```

Actually, fun also does some pad function.

Consider list1 is generated by Key-Value manipulation. One sample is, assuming index in in Range[9]

```
list1 = {{1, 5}, {6, 11}, {7, 8}, {20, 20}}

(*
    {{1,5},{6,11},{7,8},{20,20}}
*)

asso1 = Association[Rule @@@ list1]

(*
    <|1->5,6->11,7->8,20->20|>
*)

res=fun@list1

(*
    {{1,5},{6,11},{7,8},{2,0},{3,0},{4,0},{5,0},{8,0},{9,0},{10,20}}
*)
```

#### Question is convert `list1` to `res`

---

the key is the times, the value is something frequency.

```
{{10, 20}, {11, 30}} [Implies] {10, 50}
```

means greater than 10 times will add the frequency and show them in a report by column name `10+`.

Background is to show the result in a report, when the key is too large the value is too small, and add them together would be better.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is, it would be great if you could clarify. Specifically there should be a question mark somewhere in your text, I think.

Comment: @Pickett Question is convert `list1` to `res`;

Comment: And what is `res`? I don't see it defined.

Comment: @m_goldberg hi,updated, since I generate the post in Notebook and then I edit in SE and then when I didn't modify the Notebook, then I re-generate the post, and then the res disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand - or rather don't want to spend the time to understand - most of what you wrote but if the question is *just* to convert `list1` to `res` and the order doesn't need to be exactly the same then you can use

```
fun[list_, i_] := Transpose[{
   Range[i],
   ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, i], Rule @@@ list]
   }]
```

If you want to the zero elements at the end of the list then you can use

```
fun2[list_, i_] := Module[{emptyIndices},
  emptyIndices = Complement[Range[i], list[[All, 1]]];
  Join[
   list,
   Table[{x, 0}, {x, emptyIndices}]
   ]
  ]
```

Neither of these give the exact same ordering as you have in your example, since I don't see what the pattern is. Why do you have `{1,5},{6,11},{7,8}` after on another, but `{10,20}` comes last of all? Also I have assumed that `{20,20}` in your `list1` is supposed to be `{10,20}`.

**EDIT.** In order to sum elements with indices larger than a certain number together we may create another function.

```
sumFrequency[list_, i_] := Module[{lt10, gt10},
  {lt10, gt10} = GatherBy[list, #[[1]] >= 10 &];
  Append[lt10, {10, Total@gt10[[All, 2]]}]
  ]
```

Example:

```
sumFrequency[
 fun2[{{1, 5}, {6, 11}, {7, 8}, {20, 20}, {50, 10}}, 20]
 , 20]
(* Out: {{1, 5}, {6, 11}, {7, 8}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {8, 0}, {9, 
  0}, {10, 30}} *)
```

Comment: Hi, your `fun2[list1,19]==>{{1,5},{6,11},{7,8},{20,20},{2,0},{3,0},{4,0},{5,0},{8,0},{9,0},{10,0},{11,0},{12,0},{13,0},{14,0},{15,0},{16,0},{17,0},{18,0},{19,0}}`, this is without the Total@parts of list, and then, as you supposed, convert `{20,20}` to `{10,20}`.

Comment: @HyperGroups It is generally good to provide background, but if the background is hard to understand then it may backfire. I've updated my answer now, hopefully I got it right. (btw I did not downvote your question, that's someone else.)

Comment: yes, I think it's right now